# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/CommonLibrary.framework/CommonLibrary

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native

Getting the following error while trying to run iOS app on Device. But works fine on Simulator:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/CommonLibrary.framework/CommonLibrary
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1567263D-A722-4FE9-ABD0-7EC32499DBF0/CureFit.app/Frameworks/Ligero.framework/Ligero
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1567263D-A722-4FE9-ABD0-7EC32499DBF0/CureFit.app/Frameworks/CommonLibrary.framework/CommonLibrary: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1567263D-A722-4FE9-ABD0-7EC32499DBF0/CureFit.app/Frameworks/CommonLibrary.framework/CommonLibrary: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1567263D-A722-4FE9-ABD0-7EC32499DBF0/CureFit.app/Frameworks/CommonLibrary.framework/CommonLibrary: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1567263D-A722-4FE9-ABD0-7EC32499DBF0/CureFit.app/Frameworks/CommonLibrary.framework/CommonLibrary: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1567263D-A722-4FE9-ABD0-7EC32499DBF0/CureFit.app/Frameworks/CommonLibrary.framework/CommonLibrary: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
(lldb)
```

I'm new to this. It's a react native project. Can anyone help? 
Thanks :)

Comment: try remove dependency from common library

Comment: I've already marked it optional. @Cy-4AH

Comment: It's required by Ligero.framework, try read documentation where you get that library